# How can I conditionally change the values of a dropdown in a Kendo Grid?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm developing a project with ASP MVC 5, Kendo UI, and some layers. The main idea is that after I chose a value from a dropdown column in a Kendo Grid for example:

```
columns.Bound(b => b.Country).ClientTemplate("#=Country.Name#");
```

It should update a second and third column based on the previous selection:

```
columns.Bound(b => b.Category).ClientTemplate("#=Category.Name#");
columns.Bound(b => b.Client).ClientTemplate("#=Client.Name#");
```

I haven't been able to find any example or idea in the Telerik documentation or forums:

[Grid/Events](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/events)

[Grid / Editing custom editor](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editing-custom)

[Refresh/Replace DataSource of Foreignkey DropDown List](http://www.telerik.com/forums/refresh-replace-datasource-of-foreignkey-dropdown-list)

I read this example too with a normal dropdown:

[Kendo UI DropDownList on a change to trigger event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21284915/kendo-ui-dropdownlist-on-change-to-trigger-event)

Has anyone experienced something like this? My current idea is to create N number of Editor Templates:

```
@model Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.CategoryViewModel

@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)
    .DataValueField("CategoryID")
    .DataTextField("CategoryName")
    .BindTo((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["categories"])
)
```

With each of the possible Countries, however, it could be really inefficient and I still don't know how to trigger the on Change event.

Comment: Telerik has an example for [cascading dropdowns](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/dropdownlist/cascadingdropdownlist). See if that helps.

Comment: Hi @Supersnake, and how do you like it with the grid? That's the main problem. I have already checked those examples, you have 3 different templates, which are not in the same page.

Comment: Ok here is a better [example](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/Editing/cascading-dropdown-editors) that shows how to have cascading dropdowns in a grid.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to check it tomorrow because as far as I can see that JS and I'm working with MVC. I'll see if I can adapt it because currently the challenge is how to refresh the ViewData, I'd say.

Comment: I found this one: the http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/grid-inline-and-popup-editing-using-cascading-dropdownlists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long research, I was able to find a solution in this example:

[Grid InLine and PopUp Editing using Cascading DropDownLists](http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/grid-inline-and-popup-editing-using-cascading-dropdownlists)

However, it wasn't just copy and paste, I still don't know why this example is not available in the official FAQ Telerik page, but I'd like to provide the key point in order to do it:

1) You must select the **InLine** or **PopUp** edit mode:

```
.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine))
```

Why? Because when you are going to edit or add the line:

[image: Image 1]

The cascade Drop downs are fully linked to the ID, for example:
[image: Image 2]

2) Next, your new column in the grid is going to look this one:

```
columns.Bound(b => b.CategoryID).ClientTemplate("#=Category.Name#");
```

Be careful, before I we used the class as **Category** instead of the **CategoryID**, the ID is the ***crucial point***.

3) You need to change the previous approach from adding the hint to the class to the ID of the it, for example:

**Non-cascade approach:**

```
[UIHint("ClientStatus")]
public Statuses Status { get; set; }

public int StatusID { get; set; }
```

**Cascade approach:**

```
public Statuses Status { get; set; }

[UIHint("ClientStatus")]
public int StatusID { get; set; }
```

3) The editor template from the cascade approaches should look like this:

**Basic one:**

```
@model int

@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)
        .AutoBind(false)
        .DataValueField("CategoriesID")
        .DataTextField("Name")
        .DataSource(dataSource =>
        {
            dataSource.Read(read => read.Action("PopulateCategories", "FullView"))
            .ServerFiltering(true);
        })
)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m)
```

**Cascade ones:**

```
@model int

@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)
        .AutoBind(false)
        .DataValueField("ID")
        .DataTextField("Name")
        .DataSource(dataSource =>
        {
            dataSource.Read(read => read.Action("PopulateStatuses", "FullView").Data("filterCategories"))
            .ServerFiltering(true);
        })
        .CascadeFrom("CategoriesID")
)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m)
```

4) The cascade is calling a JavaScript function that looks like this:

```
function filterCategories() {
    return {
        categoriesID: $("#CategoriesID").data("kendoDropDownList").value()
    };
}
```

Where CategoriesID is the ID of the first drop down, which is generated when we edit or add a new line.

4) Finally, we need to share a JSON as a result:

**First drop down:**

```
public JsonResult PopulateCategories()
{
        return Json(CategoriesData.GetCategories(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**Second and further drop downs:**

```
public JsonResult PopulateStatuses(int categoryID)
{
        return Json(StatusesData.GetStatuses(categoryID), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the following approach for styling individual cells of grid with a template. I think you can apply this logic in order to change the values in DropDownList.

***UI for Javascript:***

```
{
    field: "EmployeeName", type: "string", width: "55px", title: "Employee Name", 
        template: "#= GetEditTemplate(data) #"
}
```

***UI for MVC:***

```
...
columns.Bound(t => t.EmployeeName).Title("Status Name").Template(@<text></text>)
    .ClientTemplate("#= GetEditTemplate(data)#").Width("55px");
...
```

***Example:*** Here data parameter is passed to the Javascript method and used in condition:

```
<script>
//Change the color of the cell value according to the given condition
function GetEditTemplate(data) {
    var html;

    if (data.StatusID == 1) {
        html = kendo.format(
        "<span class='text-success'>" +
        data.EmployeeName
        + "</span>"
        );
    }
    else {
        html = kendo.format(
        "<span class='text-danger'>Cancel</span>"
        );
    }
    return html;
}
</script>
```

For more information you might have a look at [How Do I Have Conditional Logic in a Column Client Template?](http://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/faq#how-do-i-have-conditional-logic-in-a-column-client-template). Hope this helps...